# Fastlane emulator sometimes crashes (error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer)

Tags: android, adb, fastlane

50% of the times that I run fastlane to test my project, it gives me the error `error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer` after starting the adb device. I am really not sure why this is failing, since I (should) have the latest packages. An image of the error can be seen below

[image]